# How to stop automattically typing special characters when using IDEs/Editors like NetBeans, CodeBlock?

Tags: unicode, netbeans-7, codeblocks, windows-7-x64

I have a problem when using editors (like NetBeans/CodeBlock) in windows 7. 
E.g.: If I start to initialize a text using `"`(Double/single Quotation) and text is starting with a it will give `äaaa` instead of `"aaaa"` (this web editor also the same for my PC)

How can I stop this occurrences ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are using the [US-International](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#US-International) keyboard layout.

Check the keyboard layout icon in the system tray when you have the misbehaving application focused; you can change the layout from here, or by pressing a key shortcut. (Maybe you're doing that by accident? You can turn the shortcut off, or remove the unwanted layout completely, from Control Panel → Region and Language → Keyboards and Languages → Change keyboards.)